# Convert 2e+18 to 2x10^18 in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I do the following:

```
print("{:.0e}".format(2500000000000000000))
```

Then I get out: 2e+18

How can I make this output as 2x10^18 instead (with the exponent properly superscripted).

I know using ticker you can useMathText=True which changes the output, but this doesn't seem to work with string formatting.

EDIT: Sorry folks, I was trying to simplify the question thinking it would work across. I'm attempting to make this change to a tickmark on an axis:

```
    xticklabels[-1] = '{0:.0e}'.format(xticklabels[-1]).replace('e+','x10^')
```

This works as suggested by @progo but doesn't superscript the exponent.

Comment: What exactly is the desired output in the case in question? Unicode characters like this: `2 × 10¹⁸` or TeX notation like `2 \times 10^{18}`?

Comment: I believe either should be acceptable. But with a preference to the TeX version.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala provided a fancy unicode version and I added a TeXifying version in my answer.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I have accepted @AntiiHaapala answer, but both will prove useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a **Python 2 / Python 3** solution.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
try:
    unicode
except:
    unicode = str

_superscripts = u'⁻⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹'
_superscript_map = dict(zip(map(ord, u'-0123456789'), _superscripts))

def to_fancy(number, fmt='e'):
    as_str = format(number, fmt)
    as_str, _, exponent = as_str.partition('e')
    if exponent: # will also print 10^0, add `and int(exponent)` to 
                 # not add x10^0 at all.
        exponent = unicode(int(exponent.replace('+', '')))
        exponent = exponent.translate(_superscript_map)
        as_str += u'×10' + exponent
    return as_str

>>> print(to_fancy(0.00000000321))
3.210000×10⁻⁹
```

Comment: @AntiiHaapala - I have a slight further issue with your solution, when using matplotlib backend: MacOSX the superscripted text appears fine, however when I savefig as a .png file, the superscripts appear as an empty box. Have you any experience with why this is?

Answer (score 6):

Silly solution:

```
print("{0:.0e}".format(2500000000000000000).replace('e+', 'x10^'))
=> 2x10^18
```

A TeX version:

```
def to_TeX(num):
    num = "{0:.0e}".format(num)
    mantissa, exponent = num.split('e')
    exponent = int(exponent)
    return "{0} \times 10^{{{1}}}".format(mantissa, exponent)

>>> to_TeX(1.8e21)
'2 \times 10^{21}'
```

Comment: This works, however doesnt subscript the exponent. I wasn't completely honeest in my question to try and simplify it, I have updated the above.